# Saving a foreign key in my form when a user selects a name from the dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, erb

I am a newbie to Ruby on Rails and am stumped. As part of my exercise I am creating an app that let's people put in their goal, a description, a deadline and assign it to a person.

I've got two models, a user model and a goal model. In my ERB form to create a new goal, I've created a dropdown menu of all the created users but now I have no idea how to convert that into the foreign key that gets saved.

```
<%= form_for(@goal) do |f| %>
  <% if @goal.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@goal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this goal from being saved:</h2>

......

    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :user_id, "Whose goal is it?" %><br>
       <%= collection_select(:goals, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, prompt: true ) %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The above seems to create the dropdown menu I need. I just have no idea how to get from the :name generated in the dropdown to the :user_id associated with it to submit.

Will greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frist you should use singular as `object` in `collection_select`:

```
<%= collection_select(:goal, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, prompt: true ) %>
```

Then your `collection_select` creates a `select` tag with name `goal[user_id]`. It will look like

```
    <select name="goal[user_id]">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="1" selected="selected">D. Heinemeier Hansson</option>
      <option value="2">D. Thomas</option>
      <option value="3">M. Clark</option>
    </select>
```

The options have user IDs as `value` an the names as content. So the parameter

```
params[:goal][:user_id]
```

contains the ID of the selected user. This is exactly how Rails expects the foreign key.

See the documentation of [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

Adition: there are great gems to simplify form generation, i.e. `simple_form` which reduces your form to

```
<%= simple_form_for(@goal) do |f| %>
  ...  
  <%= f.association :user %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem. Still really new to rails, and will try to go through the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is already answered but I'd like to share an awesome tutorial I found:

[Advanced forms](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms)

Just add to your 'new' controller

```
@user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.name, u.id ] }
```

Then in your form:

```
 <%= f.select(:user_id, @user_options) %>
```

Comment: oh wow that looks a lot cleaner. Thank you so much for sharing!

Comment: I've been looking for this since yesterday thank you